# OAuth2.0 request access_token using cURL security

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0

I am an newbie on using the OAuth2.0. Right now, I am requesting an access_token using cURL and it works very well as expected. But my concern now is, is this secured? because, the client_id and client_secret can be exposed? or there will be a secured way to connect/request an access_token to the OAuth server? Thank you so much.

```
$post = [
'grant_type' => 'client_credentials',
];
$ch = curl_init('http://laravelxampp.dev/oauth/access_token');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
'Authorization: Basic ZjNkMjU5ZGRkM2VkOGZmMzg0MzgzOWI6NGM3ZjZmOGZhOTNkNTljNDU1MDJjMGFlOGM0YTk1Yg==',
'Accept: application/json',
'Accept-Language: en_US'
));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$secret  = json_decode($response);
return $secret->access_token;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The request is supposed to happen over a TLS protected connection (i.e. using a https URL) instead of over plain HTTP; by doing it over TLS the confidentiality of the client secret is guaranteed.

As RFC 6749 says in https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-3.2:

> Since requests to the token endpoint result in the transmission of
> clear-text credentials (in the HTTP request and response), the
> authorization server MUST require the use of TLS as described in
> Section 1.6 when sending requests to the token endpoint.

So your example shows a non-compliant Authorization Server accepting a non-protected request.